# How to determine which vertex groups a vertex belongs to?

Tags: vertex-groups, groups

I'm using the newest version of 2.8, and I'm wanting to determine which group specific vertices belong to. I have a lot of groups and vertices, so checking them one at a time will be a lot of time spent.

I was hoping there would be some type of option that highlights vertex groups that selected vertices belong to in the group list. Something like that?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> (*Select Similar*) > *Vertex Groups*.

[image]

Also, a more precise method, in your 3D view, if you select the vertex and press <kbd>N</kbd>, you'll have access to the 3D view properties panel, if you press the *Item* tab, you'll see under *Vertex Weight* what group the vertices are part of. Then you can select them in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Vertex Groups*.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As moonboots shows, you can see the groups and weights the active vertex has assigned to it. To show a list of all selected verts gets difficult, you could have 10 selected verts and only one is part of three groups, seeing three groups would be misleading to think all verts were in the same groups.

The best visual display we have is [Weight Painting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/sculpt_paint/weight_paint/introduction.html) mode. All vertices in the active vertex group will be shaded based on their weight value.

[image: vertex group weights display]